# Need help choosing rims for fixed gear

Tags: rims, spokes

I have a Specialized Langster (really old model i think), and it got ran over, well the rims did, and I don't know which ones to get. I wanted to buy the rims and the spokes separate.

I would like some velocity b43's but I cant find them anywhere. How can I find out what rims I need?

Comment: Voting to close as product rec. Make sure you get a hub with the right spacing as well though, and you need to have someone build it.

Comment: Hi user281437. I have edited your question to try to make fit our site better. If you don't like what I've done feel free to edit again.

Comment: There are so many rim and spoke combinations that it is *very* easy to buy the wrong parts.  It sounds like you don't know what you are doing.  I'd suggest that you buy a wheel that is prebuilt or find someone to build a wheel for you.  That person will know what parts to buy.

Comment: @Batman sounds like he's reusing the hubs.

Answer (score 1):

As @Batman said in a comment, the main thing is to get the spoke count right. So count how many spokes each wheel has (they could be different). Next, [measure the width](http://sheldonbrown.com/rim-sizing.html) of the rim. You'll need to take the tires off first. And look at the tires to see what [dimensions](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) they say they are.

Next, you'll need to make some tentative decisions. I recommend keeping things as they were, unless you have a good reason to change. Do you want similar width rims, or wider / narrower? Do you want deeper profile rims? Do you want to use a similar lacing pattern? Are you going cheap or $$$?

Now take the mangled wheel(s) to your Local Bike Shop and see what rims they have that match your criteria. Get them to double check your spoke count, and to recommend what length spokes you need.

Finally, since you mention getting rims and spokes, who is going to build these wheels? Building them yourself is not hard, but it can be a slow job if you haven't done it before. Most people just pay an expert.